# Splitting string after x characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, split

I am attempting to create a program to make create a 3 lettered monogram out of any name inputted to the function through a text file. Here is the code!

```
output = 0
output_str = []
out = []

with open('Prob01.in.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    for i in lines:
        if not i.isdigit():
            output_str.append(i)
    result = ''.join(output_str)
    result = result.split()
    for names in result:
        result = names[0].title()
        out.append(result)
    print ''.join(out)
```

Here is the text file!

```
2
2
Franklin Delano Roosevelt
gabriel de paula
3
samuel a jackson
robert j cuttle
fernanda d holland
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
FDR
GDP
SAJ
```

However, I am getting:

```
FDRGDPSAJRJCFDH
```

I figured I would need to .split() after x amounts of characters, in this case 3, but how would I achieve that?

Keep in mind I am pretty new to Python, so I apologize if there is a better way to do this. I would love to learn if there is.

Thank you!

Additional:

I also need to output the result to a file, I tried:

```
output.write(''.join(monogram))
```

With output set to [] and the results were all printed in one line.

```
FDRGDPSAJRJCFDH
```

Comment: `''.join(out)` -> `'\n'.join(out)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

with open('Prob01.in.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w+') as output:
    monograms = []

    lines = f.readlines()
    pattern = re.compile("^\D+\n")  # Any non-digit simbols in line
    name_list = filter(lambda line: re.match(pattern, line), lines)
    for name in name_list:
        monograms.append(''.join(map(lambda x: x[0].title(), name.split())))

    output.write('\n'.join(monograms))
```

or

```
with open('Prob01.in.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w+') as output:
    monograms = []

    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line and not line.isdigit():
            monogram = []
            for word in line.split():
                monogram.append(word[0].upper())
            monograms.append(''.join(monogram))

    output.write('\n'.join(monograms))
```

Comment: Thank you all! I've been struggling with this problem for a days. I wanted to try it by myself but after many failed attempts, I figured it would be best to ask and learn from it. Once again, thank you :)

Comment: I actually ran into a problem! I forgot to mention that I need to write to a file, when I did `output.write(''.join(monogram))` the result was `FDRGDPSAJRJCFDH`

Comment: A '\n' character is written at the end when you call `print` function.
If you going to use `output.write` just add a '\n' after each monogram.
Or better make monograms list and call `output.write('\n'.join(monograms))`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It does not work like that, it splits after each letter

Comment: Try to `'\n'.join` a _monograms_, not _monogram_.
Try edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the String into 3 Char sections before sending them to the join, and change the join to a \n so you insert a newline between every person's name:

```
output = 0
output_str = []
out = []

with open('Prob01.in.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    for i in lines:
        if not i.isdigit():
            output_str.append(i)
    result = ''.join(output_str)
    result = result.split()
    for names in result:
        result = names[0].title()
        out.append(result)
    print '\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(out)]*3)))
```

Output:

```
FDR
GDP
SAJ
RJC
FDH
```

Though a better way might be to use regex:

```
import re
with open('Prob01.in.txt') as f:
    for m in re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z])\S* ([a-zA-Z])\S* ([a-zA-Z])\S*", f.read().upper()):
        print ''.join(m)
```

Output:

```
FDR
GDP
SAJ
RJC
FDH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your desired output within `list comprehension` like the example below:

I'm assuming your input fil is called `input_file`:

```
data = (k.rstrip().split() for k in open("input_file", 'r'))
subfinal = ("".join(j[0].upper() for j in k if not j.isdigit()) for k in data)
final = [k for k in subfinal if k != '']
for k in final:
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
FDR
GDP
SAJ
RJC
FDH
```